# Google Apps Script UI: Scroll to top of screen

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script

SETUP:

Using Google Apps Script's UI (doGet) with tabPanel option. At the bottom of each panel is  a "previous" and "next" button to navigate through the tabs.

ISSUE:

When activating a navigation button the viewing area remains at the bottom of the screen.

QUESTION:

What code can be used to jump to the top of the screen? (i.e. window.scrollTo(0,0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to interact with the browser like this. But you can control the window scrolling if you wrap up all your GUI inside your own scroll panel, instead of using the browser's one.

Then, you can use the `myScroll.setScrollPosition(y).setHorizontalScrollPosition(x)`.

Comment: Thank Henrique, I appreciate the input.  : )

Comment: Same deal with HtmlService?

Comment: @BryanP I'm not sure, but it may be the case due to caja restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

using HtmlService with IFRAME mode...

`$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");`

Comment: Thanks Bryan  : )     Glad Google allows jQuery with their HtmlService.