# window.scrollTo() not working

Tags: google-app-maker

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

Desired result: page scrolls up to top

Tried it attached to button click and nothing happens.

I have pages of information and when the user clicks on the next/previous page button at the bottom, I want the window to scroll back up to the top.

What's going wrong here? Is there some other App Maker method we're supposed to use within App Maker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out: [Google Apps Script UI: Scroll to top of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007971/google-apps-script-ui-scroll-to-top-of-screen)

I haven't tried this, but from this post something like:

```
var element = app.currentPage.getElement();
element.scrollTop = 0;
// (And if you need left as well)
element.scrollLeft = 0;
```