# Can't use window.scrollTo in google app script web app on the ios phone or ipad

Tags: javascript, ios, google-apps-script, web-applications, scroll

window.scrollTo(0,0) not work in google app script web app on the ios phone or ipad

[window.scrollTo() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44952033/window-scrollto-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
window.scrollTo(0,0)
```

I use vue as front-end and google app script as backend, and when I deploy front-end application to google app script, window.scrollTo(x,y) is work in desktop website and Android phone, but it can't work on ios mobile, I don't know what's wrong with it, I guess the wrong is about IFRAME in google app script.

This is my website:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwc4Fk_CxhXio3MC4hTrAkcpAGrnDGxFikbG6p0kQoAUoYnyFw/exec

Use iphone or Ipad and Click Start, In the bottom have "Next Area" button, and click it can't scroll to top

Anyone know how to solve this problem?